# Start a python script from grails 3

Tags: python, grails

I created a web interface in Grails 3 where you can start different pipelines written in python via a web environment. I have created a simple form with a start button. The idea is now that when you press the start button the python pipeline is started. I can't figure it out I have tried several things a example is:

```
def cmd = "python amplicon_pipeline.py -i 'inputdir' -o 'outputdir' -a 'amplicon'"
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitFor()
```

But nothing happens.
How can I get an external python script to start working when you press the start button?

Comment: Don't quote for `string.execute()` .  Make sure no quoting is needed or use `['python', 'param1', ...].execute()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy string execute versus list execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126690/groovy-string-execute-versus-list-execute)

Comment: You mean "amplicon_pipeline.py"['python', 'inputdir', 'outputdir', 'amplicon'].execute()?

Answer (score 0):

Mention the full path to python and the script file.

**Ex:**

```
def cmd = ["/usr/bin/python", "/home/rm93/Documents/project_rivm/RIVM_amplicon_pipeline/amp‌​licon_pipeline.py", "-i", "/home/rm93/Documents/Git/BIGC_test_upload/amplicon_pipeline‌​/18/upload/", "-o", "/home/rm93/Documents/Git/BIGC_test_upload/amplicon_pipeline‌​/18/output/", "-a", "16sv4"]
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println proc.text
```

Comment: I try def cmd = "/usr/bin/python /home/rm93/Documents/project_rivm/RIVM_amplicon_pipeline/amplicon_pipeline.py -i '/home/rm93/Documents/Git/BIGC_test_upload/amplicon_pipeline/18/upload/' -o '/home/rm93/Documents/Git/BIGC_test_upload/amplicon_pipeline/18/output/' -a '16sv4'" but it does nothing.

Comment: I have updated the Solution. Can you try this snippet?

Comment: I have tried your code snippet but nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Maybe the code would help? The code can be found here https://github.com/rm93/BIGC and then go to BIGC/grails-app/controllers/bigc/AmpliconController.groovy and then the pipeline function.