# error: pathspec 'CI]"' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: android, git, gradle, groovy

I want to run git command in Gradle Android with groovy. 
the command is `commit` with `skip ci` message.

```
`git commit -m "[skip ci]"`
```

I use this code in Gradle task

```
def git  = "git commit -m \"[skip ci]\"".execute()
git.waitFor()
println git.errorStream.text
```

in other case like `git pull` or `git push` it execute without any problem but in this case I'm faced with this error.

tip : `git` command run without any problem in terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy string execute versus list execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126690/groovy-string-execute-versus-list-execute)

Comment: @GenoChen thanks for your suggest but It's not.

Comment: I don't have a Groovy environment now, but it seems that the spaces are chop down before passing to the command line. And the question tells the way to prevent the early chop down.

Comment: That is, I guess `"git commit -m \"[skip ci]\"".execute()` actually executes `git commit -m "\"[skip" "ci]\""`.

Comment: That is right, with this command in terminal I've the same result as my Gradle do you have any idea how can I fix it @GenoChen

Comment: Thanks to you @GenoChen , I solved my problem with this code
    def git = ['sh', '-c', 'git commit -m "[skip ci]"'].execute()

Comment: My pleasure for solving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to solve my issue.

```
    def git = ['sh', '-c', 'git commit -m "[skip ci]"'].execute()
```